# Iterating through a multidimensional array to see the values of sub arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array:

```
winning_lines = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to see if any of the values inside the second level of arrays is `'X'`, `'X'`, `'X'`. I have this code, which is wrong as it won't return `"player"`:

```
if g[line[0..7].any?] == ['X','X','X']
  return 'Player'
end
```

How should I check if all the values in any of the subarrays are `X`?

Comment: You're on the right track. If `line` is an array containing the cells on which a player has `X`'s, try `winning_lines.any? { |l| !(l & line).empty? }`. Here [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26) is the array intersection method.  This returns `true` if the player has won, else `false`.

Comment: What is `g`? What is `line`?

Comment: @sawa It's possible I'm not writing my question out properly because I've tried to implement what everyone has suggested to the best of my abilities and nothing seems to work. g is the grid. I should post my entire method this is encapsulated in for more clarity. I'm sorry, I'm really new to all this.

`def check_winner(g)
  winning_lines = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
  winning_lines.any? do |line|
    if g[line.all?{|e| e == "X"}]
      return 'Player'
    elsif #insert code here
      return 'Computer'
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To literally do what you asked for, you can do this:

```
winning_lines.any?{|a| a.all?{|e| e == "X"}}
```

But looking into the subarray is [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). You only have three elements within a subarray, and you don't need to avoid writing duplicate `"X"`s just three times in your code.

```
winning_lines.any?{|a| a == %w[X X X]}
```

would do. Or, you can do what 7stud suggests, but `index` is actually faster than `include?`, despite it gives more information.

```
winning_lines.index(%w[X X X])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use include?():

```
return 'Player' if winning_lines.include?(['X', 'X', 'X'])
```

But it can be more efficient to use a set:

```
require 'set'

winning_lines = Set.new([[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
...

return 'Player' if winning_lines.include?(['X', 'X', 'X'])
```

`Array#include?()` requires ruby to search through the whole array when the subarray isn't present, and when the subarray is present, ruby will have to search through half the array on average.  And for every subarray, ruby has to do some comparisons of the items in the subarray to  the items in ['X', 'X', 'X'] to determine if they are equal. On the other hand, `Set#include?()` is like looking up a key in a Hash: no matter how large the set is, ruby can instantaneously determine whether the item is present in the set.